# Better way to reduce if statements

Tags: java

So I have just gotten a bunch of old code where I should improve the performance of. After looking for a while I came accross this piece of code:

```
//Reference on how the global Variables look like:
private static final int PLS_4_SYSTEM_MALFUNCTION_FL = 4;
private static final int SPS1_20_PUFFER_EMPTY = 20;
private static final int SPS1_30_STOPPERFL_LOCKED = 30;
//...

    int disturbance1 = bMessage.getDisturbanceSps1().intValue();
    int disturbance2 = bMessage.getDisturbanceSps1().intValue();

if (disturbance1 == SPS1_20_PUFFER_EMPTY && disturbance2 == 0) {
            checkWarnings(bMessage, PLS_5_PUFFER_EMPTY);
        }

if (disturbance1 == SPS1_30_STOPPERFL_LOCKED && disturbance2 == 0) {
            checkWarnings(bMessage, PLS_6_STOPPERFL_LOCKED);
        }

        if (disturbance1 == SPS1_40_DISTURBANCEFL && disturbance2 == 0) {
            if (bMessage.getDisturbanceType().intValue() == DISTURBANCETYPE_SYSTEMDISTURBANCE_SHORT) {
                checkWarnings(bMessage, PLS_3_SHORTDISTURBANCE_FL);
            }
            else if (bMeldung.getStoerungsartMde().intValue() == DISTURBANCETYPE_SYSTEMDISTURBANCE_LONG) {
                checkWarnings(bMessage, PLS_4_SYSTEMMALFUNCTION_FL);
            }
        }
//...
```

This is just a small example of the code. There are like 300+ more lines that goes on like this.

Now I know that there are many answers on the web already, and I have looked at some of them, but I am unsure which answer would help me the best in this case.

Comment: this is more about code review, so SO may not be the best place to post this. Also, what makes you think this isn't an appropriate way?

Comment: How did you figure out that there is performance deggradation occurs with multiple `if-else`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help !!

```
if(disturbance2 == 0) {
    
        switch (disturbance1){
        
            case SPS1_20_PUFFER_EMPTY:
            
            checkWarnings(bMessage, PLS_5_PUFFER_EMPTY);
            
            break;
            
            case SPS1_30_STOPPERFL_LOCKED:
            
            checkWarnings(bMessage, PLS_5_PUFFER_EMPTY);
            
            break;
            
            case SPS1_40_DISTURBANCEFL:
            
                if (bMessage.getDisturbanceType().intValue() == DISTURBANCETYPE_SYSTEMDISTURBANCE_SHORT) {
                    checkWarnings(bMessage, PLS_3_SHORTDISTURBANCE_FL);
                }
                else if (bMeldung.getStoerungsartMde().intValue() == DISTURBANCETYPE_SYSTEMDISTURBANCE_LONG) {
                    checkWarnings(bMessage, PLS_4_SYSTEMMALFUNCTION_FL);
                }
                
            break;
                
        }
    }
```

also you can write

```
if(disturbance2 != 0){
  // return or exit if requires
}
```

// then start switch() , you can remove one branch of block

Answer (score 1):

You could change that to something like enums, new-style switches etc. This can certainly make the code more readable and maintainable.

However, you were talking about enhancing *performance*. Changing this code most likely will have hardly any impact on performance, at least not in a positive way.

If you want to improve performance, measure and find the bottlenecks in the code and focus on those.

Answer (score 0):

Switch on disturbance1 can help.

Check out the new switch style from Java17. It makes code really lean.